# Spring validation don't executed

Tags: java, spring, validation, controller, annotations

It works with directly executing. But i need in the first row of controller to get results from bindingResults. I can't use @Validated annotation cause my Spring version is too old. and @Valid don't working for me

So what i have

**in controller:**

```
@Autowired
private EmpValidator empValidator;


@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(EmpValidator);
}

@RequestMapping
public String addOrder(@Valid @ModelAttribute EmpOrder order, BindingResults bindingResults){
//getRid
//empValidator.validate(order, bindingResult);

if (bindingResults.hasError())
//do something

}

}
```

**validator**

```
public class EmpValidator implements Validator{
if (number.isEmpty()
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhiteSpace("number","Error filling field number");

}
```

Comment: what spring and java version do you use?

Comment: Spring 3.0.5 RELEASE then i add this dependency for @Valid annotation       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency> java version 1.6

Comment: Please don't add additional information in the comments, instead edit your question. Also `@Valid` **without** an actual implementation (like hibernate-validator) is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to add a javax.validation.api into my artifact. Clean artifact folder, and build artifact solved the problem